# Is it possible to have a Python core and ASP.Net MVC GUI?

Tags: python, asp.net-mvc, django

I have a project that needs to use Python for the Core, my project is all about network security so my Python does Sniffing, Parsing, Detecting etc.

To make the GUI easier for the user I will deploy an HTTP Server (that supports ASP.Net in Linux) and I will use it as an Web.API then it will "connect" to the Python core to get the information it needed to display.

Is my theory correct? I use WebAPI recently but I'm not entirely sure if it can be use this way like Real Time Updating from the core (lets assume the port from core to api is always open)

Any Suggestion for my setup? Or do you think learning Django is better? I'm not really that efficient with Python yet so I'm not sure if its more plausible in Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's certainly *possible* but whether it's desirable or not is another matter.

You would end up having to write some kind of server in your Python application, run it separately from your ASP.Net server and have that connect directly to it. Note, I don't know anything about ASP.Net, but this is the general pattern for most language interop.

Of course, this means you'd be opening a socket to your Python server on most HTTP requests, which could end up being pretty slow and unreliable, depending on whether the server is run locally, and how the implementation is done.

Instead, you may prefer to integrate the HTTP server into your Python application using one of the following libraries, along with [uwsgi](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

- [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html)
- [Cyclone](http://cyclone.io/) (Great for Twisted applications!)
- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

[Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) could also be used for this, but you'd most likely have to restructure your entire application, and it's kind of massive - you'd most likely be better off using one of the microframeworks above.

Comment: At most it will run locally.

I have some questions:
1. Why do I need to make a server in my python application, can't it be like the web server uses REST API Calls and the core will just do HTTP Calls to it.

2. I don't get the HTTP Server in Python Application, I mean is this another language aside from Django or I am looking at this at the wrong perspective? 

Sorry I'm new in this kind of things so I appreciate the help :)

Comment: @HecchiAves Well, there's no reason you can't make it use REST API calls, it just seems like an overcomplicated design. Besides, keeping all your code in one language often helps you focus on that language, which is especially useful if you're new to it. As for Django, you'd still be writing in Python, but it has a defined structure that might be very different from what you've already done.

Comment: I see, thanks for the fast response. So if I follow your suggestion and I use uwsgi with Bottle or Flash, I'm still gonna use python but with a different framework? different from Django?

Comment: @HecchiAves Yes, that's right. Try playing around with them - it's a case of finding a framework that you like.